# JSONPath: Find Items where sub-item criteria is in list of strings

Tags: json, jsonpath

having the following book store I want to find all books that match the categories 'fiction' **and** 'fantasy'

```
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                "price": 8.95
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "price": 12.99
            },
            {
                "category": "adventure",
                "author": "Herman Melville",
                "title": "Moby Dick",
                "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
                "price": 8.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fantasy",
                "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
                "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
                "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
                "price": 22.99
            }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

I found this example `[?(@.size in ['S', ‘M'])]` [here](https://docs.hevodata.com/sources/engg-analytics/streaming/rest-api/writing-jsonpath-expressions/#filters) which looks exactly like what I want but I could not get it working at https://jsonpath.com

This is what I tried:

```
$.store.book.[?(@.category in ['fiction','fantasy'])]
```

Looking for just a single criteria value works at https://jsonpath.com:

```
$.store.book.[?(@.category == 'fiction')]
```

Thank you for any hint pointing me into the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [logical OR](https://docs.hevodata.com/sources/engg-analytics/streaming/rest-api/writing-jsonpath-expressions/#filters) ( || symbol) for multiple criteria.

### updated expression:

```
$.store.book[?(@.category == 'fiction' || @.category == 'fantasy')]
```

### Output:

[image]

### Reference:

https://docs.hevodata.com/sources/engg-analytics/streaming/rest-api/writing-jsonpath-expressions/#filters